# Vertical center div inside another div + image

Tags: html, css, image, center

I have a `div` which contains an image and another `div` with text. The image serves as a background image (I have some reasons, why I do not want to do it via the `background-image` property). The text of the inner `div` should be vertically centered in the outer `div`.

The outer `div` has `width: 100%` for responsive behavior with narrow devices.

My approach works as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLo80jdh/

One thing I need to change is to set the `height` of the image to `auto` in order to *not* (!) stretch it. However, if I set `height: auto` then the text of the inner `div` is not vertically centered anymore as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLo80jdh/1/

My question is: How can I set the height to auto (no stretched image) + vertically center the text?

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wLo80jdh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked you fiddle and adjusted it to fit your needs. i used `flexbox` for that
https://jsfiddle.net/x9u0dxm8/

Comment: Great solution. Other provided solutions seem also to work, but with your solution the `inner1` class still has full height, which I need for my hover effect to work (the hover effect is not in my simplified jsfiddle example).

Answer (score 0):

Remove absolute position from `.outer .inner1` and set it to `.outer .text` and also add this to that class:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

**Update**

If you want `.inner1` to have height leave `position:absolute` and remove `display:table` from it.

Full (updated) example here https://jsfiddle.net/wLo80jdh/5/

Comment: great answer. let me ask you one more thing. why in your example has `.outer .inner1` a height of 0 (when I inspect it with browser tools)? I would need it to have a size because a have a `hover` effect on it (the fiddle is a simplified example).

Comment: take a look at my answer. `.outer .inner1` has correct height there.

Comment: in that case leave absolute position for `.inner1` and remove `display:table`.. see updated answer with new jsfiddle